# What is the right approach in using Thrift in invoking webservice on Websphere?

Tags: web-services, websphere, thrift

I am writing an app on Thrift and webservice deployed on Websphere. Thrift client will be calling thrift server which inturn make a webservice call to webservice deployed on websphere.

1. Where will I host Thrift server implementation since it will be standalone app? Can it be started before/on startup of Websphere app server?
2. Shall I run Thrift as a standalone and then how will Thrift server get the common VOs being shared between Thrift server (which is client to webservice) and server(webservice hosted on Websphere)?
3. What should be right approach in this case since Thrift will be opening a socket which is making a websphere call even though both servers are collocated?
4. Is it safe to use sockets as a medium of rmi/rpc instead of http? What will be security loopholes since port will be opened for communication?

Thanks.
Quick reply will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Thrift service might be implemented either as a standalone application or as an webapp running on the same app server. In latter case thrift service doesn't have to serve any http requests, it should just start thrift server on app startup/shutdown. The advantage is that you can utilize all appserver infrastructure: lifecycle, monitoring, JMX, etc.
2. To share VOs between two JVMs, it's usually enough to make them 'implements Serializable' and add classes to both classpaths. Sharing within single JVM is trivial. So, there should be no problems here.
3. Yes, socket communication is just fine, even if servers are collocated.
4. Yes, it is safe enough, if configured properly. Restricting access to corresponding ports with firewall is probably the easiest.